# Manage PostgreSQL Privileges with Ansible

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I've used the Ansible Galaxy role geerlingguy.postgresql[1] to create a PostgreSQL server. But I'm a bit stuck onto how I can create a user in PostgreSQL which has the following rights:

- Create tables in the database
- Doing SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE queries

How can I achieve this?

My config at the moment looks like this:

```
postgresql_databases:
  - name: mydb
    owner: myuser

postgresql_users:
  - name: myuser
    db: mydb
    objs: ALL_IN_SCHEMA
    privs: SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CONNECT,CREATEDB
    role_attr_flags: CREATEROLE
```

[1] - https://galaxy.ansible.com/geerlingguy/postgresql

Comment: So ... is ansible throwing you an error or what? The `vars` look reasonable enough?

Answer (score 0):

Uh, postgres permission model is a mess (... not a mess, just is more complicated than everyone would like it to be).

You need to configure FOUR separate things for user to have an access (not counting the creation of the user itself and configuring `hg_hba.conf` for network-level access):

- database priveleges (type: database)
- schema priveleges (type: schema)
- table priveleges (type: table)
- sequence priveleges (type: sequence)

Moreover, when you do this, you need to have admin access to postgress, and it should not be root (it should be 'postgres' user for most Postgres installations).